# How to rebind my View to a new data context on visibility change of window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF Window which is bind to viewmodel as data context. 
 In view

- In view I have a listview and in its view a gridview in which i have some static columns

  ```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" Margin="0,76,0,0">
      <ListView.View>
          <GridView attachedBehaviors:GridViewColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding PackagesColumns}">
              <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn Header="URI" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding URI}"></GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn Header="ABC" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReferencedPackages}"></GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>                                
  </ListView>
  ```
- In view model i have bound dynamic column to gridview using observable collection
- To generate dynamic columns i have used depenency property

  ```
   public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "BindableColumns",
          typeof(ObservableCollection<GridViewColumn>),
          typeof(GridViewColumnsBehavior),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));

  private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(
      DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      GridView dataGrid = source as GridView;

      var columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<GridViewColumn>;

      if (dataGrid != null)
      {
          // dataGrid.Columns.Clear();

          if (columns == null)
          {
              return;
          }

          foreach (GridViewColumn column in columns)
          {
              dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
          }
  ```

On click of a button1 i hide the view. Now on click of button2 the viewmodel is again visible and I have to give a new object of viewmodel as datacontext but that doesn't updates the view with the new columns that i have binded using dependency property.

So is it possible to update content  the view with new ViewModel on visiblity change?

Comment: Can you include your code? I am not sure if I understand your question, but setting a different DataContext should cause all the bindings to refresh. Keep in mind though, that a new UI will not be generated, so only bound values will get refreshed.

Comment: Hi rachel actually I have everything else refreshes but I am using a dependency property on my gridview to generate columns. those dynamically generated columns are not getting refreshed. I am updating the question with code

Comment: Does your `BindableColumnsPropertyChanged` code get hit when you switch views? Also, what happens to your normal hardcoded `GridViewColumn` from XAML?